# Why does my laptop keep opening and closing a cmd prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I don't use command prompts often, but right now I'm noticing one open and close immediately. I can't even see any text in it because it's so fast, but it's happening. How can I get to the bottom of this? What is going on??

Comment: This can likely be malicious software running scripts. Run an anti-malware scan at the root level.

Comment: MalwareBytes Anti-Rootkit is a crowd favorite.

Comment: Could be malware.  Could be other possibilities.  Are there any tasks in the task bar?  Logon scripts?  Remote management software (which I've encountered most frequently on business PCs)?  What software is running (use TaskList)?  I know that isn't narrowing down much, but I'm pointing out there are other possible causes.

Comment: Did you try to take a screenshot of the command prompt to see what is running?

Comment: use sysmon to log all process activity on your Windows. Later you can see the result in eventlog

Comment: @spike_66 how would I take a screenshot of a command prompt window that opens and closes extremely quickly?